# NodeJs / NestJs wait for async to be done and return results

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a controller on nestjs that is writing a job to the queue.
The job processing suppose to last between 100MS to 5000MS.
I don't want to disconnect the client until I have the answer.

How can I do that and not running a while loop?
write now I have this very bad code:

```
@Post('job')
async job(@Body() request): Promise<JobRes>{
   const job = await this.bullQueue.add('hande', request);

   while(true){ //UGLY AND BAD
       const state = await job.getState();
       if(state == 'completed'){
          return await this.db.findByJobId(job.id);
       }
       await sleet(1_000);
   }
}
```

This solution require a lot of resources from the event loop and is not safe at all.
I'm looking for a better solution to hand the request untill I have response.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to wait for the result then why add it to queue?

Comment: This code has some `await`s in places I wouldn't expect them. Is adding something to the queue really asynchronous? Is getting the state of a job really asynchronous? Seems a little strange to me ...

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc the purpose of the queue *may* be to execute the requests one after the other, ie a new request may only be handled once the old ones have completed.

Answer (score 0):

Hei!

```
import { setTimeout } from "timers/promises"
const abc = async()=>{
   while((await job.getState())!=='completed') await setTimeout(500)
   return await this.db.findByJobId(job.id);
}
```

This approach has little to do with mind, while will do its work. See comments.

Comment: While this is a bit better strucured then OP's code, it's in principle the same, ie waiting in a `while` loop until a condition is fulfilled. (Letting aside you probably want to compare with `!==` instead of `===`)

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher, I edited my comment. The principle is the same, yes, but it allows the EventLoop to do its job until there's awaited, so what's your point?

Comment: The point is, that this way, the whole process always takes at least 500ms to complete, even if the original request only takes 100ms ... And if that timeout is poorly chosen, the server may be sitting around quite a while doing nothing but waiting for the timout to finish.. And so will the client, waiting for the server's response ...

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher, I see your point and it is clear and solid. So what's better? Turning job.getState into EventEmitter and subscribing to events?

Comment: Either that or making `job` a promise and thus `await`able ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `request`,  `job` or `bullQueue` is. But generally you have the following possibilities:

1. make the `job` to be a promise -- ie `bullQueue.add()` must return a `Promise<Promise<T>>` or depending on what `request` is you may be able to turn it into a promise directly without adding it to some queue --  so you can do something like this

   ```
   const job = await this.bullQueue.add('hande', request);
   // const job = request.toPromise();   just some pseudo code, wrapping request into a promise 
   await job;

   ...
   ```
2. make `job` emit an event when it's finished so you can do something like this

   ```
   const job = await this.bullQueue.add('hande', request);
   await new Promise(res => {
     //attach the event listener to job
     //and once the event is raised, resovle the promise
     job.on("completed", () =>{ res(); });
   })

   ...
   ```

If you cannot change the implementation of your `job` you are pretty much out of luck, ie you can only wait for your condition to become fulfilled ... See @Michael Lampu answer on how to make this a bit more structured ...